# Alternatives to Bootstrap JS does not work inside shadow dom

Tags: google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom, content-script

I tried to create a shadow DOM for encapsulating the content Script elements and then apply Bootstrap styles and also make Bootstrap Modal work inside a shadow Dom so it can encapsulate itself from the Webpage styles and Scripts.  It is successful in displaying the content but Bootstrap js scripts don't work.

I tried injecting all the Styles and  Script files inside the Shadow DOM. Bootstrap Styles work, Bootstrap Scripts don't work

```
$(#id) //the usual way to access a id using jQuery

parentofShadowtree.shadowRoot.querySelector('#id') //to select a element inside shadow DOM
```

I think the error is because the Bootstrap scripts are not able to access the elements as they usually would.

I believe since the way of accessing elements has changed, these script files doesn't work.

Am I right? Is there a way to overcome this problem

Comment: You're right. Don't use Shadow DOM with Boostrap scripts. To overcome this problem maybe you could overload the querySelector method, but I haven't tried.

Comment: @Supersharp I guess that is super hard for me and decided to go without shadow dom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you still want to use Shadow DOM the workaround is to put the Bootstrap UI elements in the light DOM and then insert then with  in the Shadow DOM.

```js
customElements.define( 'c-e', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
            .innerHTML = `
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">CSS Only</button>
                <slot name="dropdown"></slot>`
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `<section slot="dropdown">        
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown button
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </section>`
    }
} )
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<c-e></c-e>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is what I want. Awesome! Will go through the solution

Comment: I'm having a similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795202/making-javascript-script-available-to-shadow-dom?noredirect=1#comment107562217_60795202. Can you please help?

Comment: @methuselah sorry I don't know Angular well but I suppose you should put your elements in the light dom (as describe above)

Comment: so, is it loading bootstrap's styles twice?

Comment: nevermind, I just tested it and it only loads once

Comment: I don't think this works when you use Bootstrap components (that rely on JavaScript) inside a custom element, inside a custom element. The light DOM of the inner custom element is still inside the outer custom element's shadow DOM.